# Wordpress w.Nginx Proxy Manager

Tags: wordpress, nginx, reverse-proxy

I have my WordPress instance setup, connected to the database and functioning perfectly when accessed via the docker host IP and port 2142 (mapped to 80.) I have this in my Nginx Proxy Manager the same way I do for all of my other proxy hosts and get 502 bad gateway (openresty) SSL enabled or Disabled makes no difference.

**Compose file:**

```
    
services:
  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:latest
    volumes:
      - wordpress_data:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - "2142:80"
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
     - WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=REDACTED
     - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=REDACTED
     - WORDPRESS_DB_USER=REDACTED
     - WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=REDACTED
     - WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX=REDACTED
volumes:
  wordpress_data: {}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have recently fixed this. This is the code:

```
    version: '3'
services:
  landing-db:
    container_name: ${CONTAINER_DB_NAME}
    image: ${DB-IMAGE:-mariadb}:${DB_VERSION:-latest}
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ${DB_FILES}:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}

  landing-wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - landing-db
    container_name: ${CONTAINER_SITE_NAME}
    #image: ${SITE_IMAGE:-wordpress}:${SITE_VERSION:-latest}
    build:
      context: ${DOCKERFILE_CONTEXT}
      dockerfile: ${DOCKERFILE_NAME}
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ${SITE_FILES}:/var/www/html
      - ${PHP_INI}:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php.ini
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: ${CONTAINER_DB_NAME}
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
      WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX: ${WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX}
    logging:
      options:
        max-size: ${LOGGING_OPTIONS_MAX_SIZE:-200k}
    links:
      - landing-db
    
  landing-nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: landing-nginx
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ${NGINX_CONFIG}:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      #- ${NGINX_MY_INCLUDE_FILES}:/etc/nginx/my_include_files
      - ${SITE_FILES}:/var/www/html
    expose:
      - "80"
    #ports:
    #  - "8080:80"
    links:
      - landing-wordpress
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=${DOMAIN},www.${DOMAIN}
      #- LETSENCRYPT_HOST=${DOMAIN},www.${DOMAIN}
      #- LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=${LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL}

networks:
  default:
    name: ${NETWORK}
```

I also have a .env file where everything with ${variable_name} is specified.
I built this with dockerfile:

```
   #
# NOTE: THIS DOCKERFILE IS GENERATED VIA "apply-templates.sh"
#
# PLEASE DO NOT EDIT IT DIRECTLY.
#

FROM php:8.1-fpm-alpine

# persistent dependencies
RUN set -eux; \
    apk add --no-cache \
# in theory, docker-entrypoint.sh is POSIX-compliant, but priority is a working, consistent image
        bash \
# Ghostscript is required for rendering PDF previews
        ghostscript \
# Alpine package for "imagemagick" contains ~120 .so files, see: https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/pull/497
        imagemagick \
    ;

# install the PHP extensions we need (https://make.wordpress.org/hosting/handbook/handbook/server-environment/#php-extensions)
RUN set -ex; \
    \
    apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
        $PHPIZE_DEPS \
        freetype-dev \
        icu-dev \
        imagemagick-dev \
        libjpeg-turbo-dev \
        libpng-dev \
        libwebp-dev \
        libzip-dev \
        
    ; \
    \
    docker-php-ext-configure gd \
        --with-freetype \
        --with-jpeg \
        --with-webp \
    ; \
    docker-php-ext-install -j "$(nproc)" \
        bcmath \
        exif \
        gd \
        intl \
        mysqli \
        zip \
        pdo_mysql \
    ; \
# WARNING: imagick is likely not supported on Alpine: https://github.com/Imagick/imagick/issues/328
# https://pecl.php.net/package/imagick
    pecl install imagick-3.6.0; \
    docker-php-ext-enable imagick; \
    rm -r /tmp/pear; \
    \
# some misbehaving extensions end up outputting to stdout  (https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/issues/669#issuecomment-993945967)
    out="$(php -r 'exit(0);')"; \
    [ -z "$out" ]; \
    err="$(php -r 'exit(0);' 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)"; \
    [ -z "$err" ]; \
    \
    extDir="$(php -r 'echo ini_get("extension_dir");')"; \
    [ -d "$extDir" ]; \
    runDeps="$( \
        scanelf --needed --nobanner --format '%n#p' --recursive "$extDir" \
            | tr ',' '\n' \
            | sort -u \
            | awk 'system("[ -e /usr/local/lib/" $1 " ]") == 0 { next } { print "so:" $1 }' \
    )"; \
    apk add --no-network --virtual .wordpress-phpexts-rundeps $runDeps; \
    apk del --no-network .build-deps; \
    \
    ! { ldd "$extDir"/*.so | grep 'not found'; }; \
# check for output like "PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'foo' (tried: ...)
    err="$(php --version 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)"; \
    [ -z "$err" ]

# set recommended PHP.ini settings
# see https://secure.php.net/manual/en/opcache.installation.php
RUN set -eux; \
    docker-php-ext-enable opcache; \
    { \
        echo 'opcache.memory_consumption=128'; \
        echo 'opcache.interned_strings_buffer=8'; \
        echo 'opcache.max_accelerated_files=4000'; \
        echo 'opcache.revalidate_freq=2'; \
        echo 'opcache.fast_shutdown=1'; \
    } > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/opcache-recommended.ini
# https://wordpress.org/support/article/editing-wp-config-php/#configure-error-logging
RUN { \
# https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php
# https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/issues/420#issuecomment-517839670
        echo 'error_reporting = E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_CORE_ERROR | E_CORE_WARNING | E_COMPILE_ERROR | E_COMPILE_WARNING | E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR'; \
        echo 'display_errors = Off'; \
        echo 'display_startup_errors = Off'; \
        echo 'log_errors = On'; \
        echo 'error_log = /dev/stderr'; \
        echo 'log_errors_max_len = 1024'; \
        echo 'ignore_repeated_errors = On'; \
        echo 'ignore_repeated_source = Off'; \
        echo 'html_errors = Off'; \
    } > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/error-logging.ini

RUN set -eux; \
    version='5.9.3'; \
    sha1='cab576e112c45806c474b3cbe0d1263a2a879adf'; \
    \
    curl -o wordpress.tar.gz -fL "https://wordpress.org/wordpress-$version.tar.gz"; \
    echo "$sha1 *wordpress.tar.gz" | sha1sum -c -; \
    \
# upstream tarballs include ./wordpress/ so this gives us /usr/src/wordpress
    tar -xzf wordpress.tar.gz -C /usr/src/; \
    rm wordpress.tar.gz; \
    \
# https://wordpress.org/support/article/htaccess/
    [ ! -e /usr/src/wordpress/.htaccess ]; \
    { \
        echo '# BEGIN WordPress'; \
        echo ''; \
        echo 'RewriteEngine On'; \
        echo 'RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]'; \
        echo 'RewriteBase /'; \
        echo 'RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]'; \
        echo 'RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f'; \
        echo 'RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d'; \
        echo 'RewriteRule . /index.php [L]'; \
        echo ''; \
        echo '# END WordPress'; \
    } > /usr/src/wordpress/.htaccess; \
    \
    chown -R www-data:www-data /usr/src/wordpress; \
# pre-create wp-content (and single-level children) for folks who want to bind-mount themes, etc so permissions are pre-created properly instead of root:root
# wp-content/cache: https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/issues/534#issuecomment-705733507
    mkdir wp-content; \
    for dir in /usr/src/wordpress/wp-content/*/ cache; do \
        dir="$(basename "${dir%/}")"; \
        mkdir "wp-content/$dir"; \
    done; \
    chown -R www-data:www-data wp-content; \
    chmod -R 755 wp-content

VOLUME /var/www/html

COPY --chown=www-data:www-data wp-config-docker.php /usr/src/wordpress/
COPY ./docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/

RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh"]

ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

The docker file is takes from docker-library. You can search it with name "wordpress".

The secret in this case is "expose: 80". It is the port exposed between containers. This will be added on Nginx proxy manager with: {service-name}:{exposed port of nginx service}.

Do not forget to be on the same network.